# Cannot Install Wine Windows platform loader both from Terminal and software Center

Tags: installation, command-line, apt, software-center, wine

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my PC. I want to install Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, so I tried to install WINE.

I tried to install from the Terminal and from the Software Center. Both times, it failed in the middle of process. This is the error.

```
W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Something wrong with the repositories, as you can see from the `404 not found` part. Have you tried other repositories/sources? You can change them through Edit > Software Sources on Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: I dont find edit option in the Software Center. I tried wine 1.5. Should I go for any other version?

Comment: What exactly is giving that error? Wine installation or MS Visual Studio installation through Wine? I seriously wouldn't recommend installing MS Visual Studio at all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with my server. As I switched my download Server from Pakistan to main server I am able to download and install wine. Thanks for sparing time!